# Div positioning, issue with columns

Tags: html, css

I've got a pretty simple page, which have two div (`menu` and `content`), inside one `main` div. I can't figure out how can I extend `main` div height depending of height `menu` or `content`, I am only able to do it now for `content` div.

You can see this thing on fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nLjnn/

HTML structure:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="menu"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
    width: 908px;
    padding: 10px 20px 20px 10px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgb(159, 159, 159);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rga(159, 159, 159);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgb(159, 159, 159);
    min-height: 300px;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 1px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.menu {
    width: 170px;
    min-height: 570px;
    left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background: yellow;
}
.content {
    width: 728px;
    min-height: 450px;
    margin-left: 180px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background: gray;
}
```

There can be any amount of content in `menu` div or `content` div, so I need to scale height of `main` div respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing

`position:absolute`,

adding

```
display:inline-block;
```

and adjusting width with % should fix the issue. I hope it will help you a bit.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nLjnn/5/)

Comment: Don't forget to vertical-align:top on one or both of the divs in question as they will not align to the top otherwise and will appear broken.

Comment: Its in the fiddle I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to do away with absolute positioning in the example provided and make both `.menu` and `.content` inline-block;

```
.menu {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 170px;
    min-height: 570px;
    background: yellow;
}
.content {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 724px;
    min-height: 450px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background: gray;
}
```

Let me know if that doesn't meet the need. [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/nLjnn/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Using `float:left;` on all elements should work

http://jsfiddle.net/nLjnn/3/

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="menu"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>


.main {
    padding: 10px 20px 20px 10px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgb(159, 159, 159);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rga(159, 159, 159);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgb(159, 159, 159);
    position: relative;
    float:left;
}
.menu {
    width: 170px;
    min-height: 570px;
    float:left;
    background: yellow;
}
.content {
    width: 728px;
    float:left;
    min-height: 450px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background: gray;
}
```